# Laravel 5.1 - Overloaded routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have a homegrown, Laravel 5.1 base application on top of which I build specific applications. The base application uses a named route for login, naturally called "login", which listens for GET /login.

In one of my specific applications, I attempted to overload that route to send the requests to a different controller. It seemed to work for a while, but then it started going to the base application's controller again. I'm sure I changed something to break it, but the problem is that I can't figure out how to fix it again.

My base application routes are all defined in app/Http/Routes/core.php. The relevant route:

```
Route::get('login', [
    'as' => 'login',
    'uses' => '\MyVendor\Core\Http\Controllers\AuthController@getLogin'
]);
```

My specific application routes are defined in app/Http/Routes/app1.php. The relevant route:

```
Route::get('login', [
    'as' => 'login',
    'uses' => 'App1\AuthController@getLogin'
]);
```

App2 and App3 are defined similarly. My app/Http/routes.php adds these routes like this:

```
require 'Routes/core.php';

Route::group(['domain' => 'app1.com'], function() {
    require 'Routes/app1.php';
});

Route::group(['domain' => 'app2.com', function() {
    require 'Routes/app2.php';
});

Route::group(['domain' => 'app3.com', function() {
    require 'Routes/app3.php';
});
```

The problem I am seeing is that visiting app1.com/login, app2.com/login, and app3.com/login all result in the execution of `\MyVendor\Core\Http\Controllers\AuthController@getLogin` rather than `App1\AuthController@getLogin`.

EDIT: I have changed the problem description since I was describing it incorrectly as a problem with calls to `route('login')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index of the routes in Laravel follows a `"$domain$uri"` format, therefore routes with a domain won't overwrite those without. A fallback route without a domain should be declared after the domain group, so it is later in the route collection and won't match before a route with a matching domain.

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't seen any documentation regarding "$domain$uri" indexing. If it's out there, I must have read right past it.

Comment: If it's useful you can find it in the source [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php#L67)

Comment: That was going to be my next step, but I figured I could outsource that question while I kept working on other aspects of my project. Thanks again!

Comment: Okay, so the next level of questioning is here... When I define a fallback route for 'login', it seems to always take precedence over the domain-defined route of the same name. Shouldn't calls to route('login') always take the domain into account?

Comment: For reverse lookups the index is simply the "as" key of the route array. Therefore your fallback route coming last will overwrite the other routes - indeed unfortunate for your particular usage.

Comment: Actually, I have the fallback defined before the domain routes. The idea was that I'd want the domain routes to overload it. The problem is my order doesn't seem to matter. All calls to route("login") return the fallback route, not the last-defined route named 'login'.

Comment: I just tested this and found that route names defined later, even if inside a domain group, overwrite their earlier counterparts. Something else may well be amiss in your routes to cause this.

Comment: Crap. I incorrectly described the problem. I'm a terrible OP right now... I technically do not know if "route('login')" is failing because all of my 'login' routes are GET /login. The problem is that when I actually visit GET /login, I am served the base application's controller-method instead of the domain group's controller-method.

Comment: That sounds like your original question again :P If you want GET /login to serve the domain group's route if the domain matches, the domain-less route must come after the domain group. If you want to overwrite the domain-less route's _name_ with a route in a domain group, the domain-less route must come before the domain group (and therefore can no longer function as a fallback).

Comment: Yeah, I tried about every possible combination of route setups that I could think of, and I wound up confusing myself pretty well -- couldn't keep my symptoms and explanations straight. If I'm understanding you correctly, Laravel is set up in such a way that what I'm trying to implement is effectively a paradox. Does that sound like a pretty correct summary at this point?

Comment: Not quite a paradox, but you're unlikely to get this patched in core since Laravel isn't maintained with the base application pattern you're following in mind. The recommendation would be to abstract common functionality into separate packages with their own service providers, and avoid the concept of fallbacks altogether.

Comment: It just seems really strange that one behavior goes front-to-back and a closely related behavior is back-to-front.

Answer (score 0):

"the most recent definition for a route is the effective route"

This is not a bug, this is the expected behaviour, a simple example would be setting a variable to `value 1` then setting it to `value 2`, of course the (most) recent value takes place.

Comment: I was referring to the behavior in which a route defined outside of a domain block can apparently *not* be overloaded inside of a domain block.